# How to make Date locale-independent?

Tags: java, locale, gmt

I have a db, that stores dates in `OleDateTime` format, in GMT timezone. I've implemented a class, extending `Date` in java to represent that in classic date format. But my class is locale-dependent (I'm in GMT+2). Therefore, it converts the date in the db as `date - 2 hours`. How do I make it convert the date correctly? I want my class to be locale-independent, always using GMT timezone. Actually, the question is:

```
class MyOleDateTime extends Date {

    static {
        Locale.setDefault(WhatGoesHere?)
    }

    // ... some constructors
    // ... some methods
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, it's better to use the Calendar object like suggested in other answers. However, if you *really* want to set global timezone, you can use `TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));` early in your application code. There is also `user.timezone` Java system property.

Also (just fun to know), it appears that the only country actually living by GMT/UTC time (without daylight saving changes) is Liberia.

In fact, `Date` objects per se are *always* locale- and timezone-independent. Its `getTime()` method will always return the number of milliseconds passed since January 1, 1970 00:00:00 (not counting leap seconds) *in UTC*. But if you want to get something else than milliseconds, you have to use `Calendar`, which *is* timezone-dependent. But it is the right way to go. You don't use that deprecated methods in `Date` class, do you?

Comment: @Michael But I really do not have an access to the client code, that uses my class. And it *does* uses the deprecated Date api. What should I do then?

Comment: @Alexander I actually don't. But I'm pretty sure, that my clients do. So how do I make things right, without breaking their code?

Comment: @folone: If you can't get them to correct their already broken code, you'll have to live with an application that can break anytime some code changes the default timezone.

Comment: @Michael: That's definetely not cool. I'll try to convince guys from other teams to change their code accordingly. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

As Michael Borgwardt has already said, the Java `Date` object does not know anything about timezones. It's just a wrapper for a number of milliseconds since 01-01-1970 00:00:00 UTC.

You start dealing with timezones only when you for example convert the `Date` object to a `String` using a `DateFormat`. You set the timezone on the `DateFormat` to specify in which timezone you want to see the `Date`.

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

String text = df.format(date);  // text will contain date represented in UTC
```

Answer (score 2):

A *Date* *is* locale-independent, always using GMT timezone. It's just a wrapper around a millisecond timestamp in GMT (more correctly: UTC).

The only things in `Date` that are timezone dependant are the deprecated methods like `getDay()` - that's why they're deprecated. Those use the default time zone. The correct thing to do is to avoid using those deprecated methods - *not* to set the default timezone to UTC! That could cause problems elsewhere, and you can't prevent other parts of the code from setting the default timezone to something else.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [Calendar](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) object:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"),
                                    locale);
```

Comment: My class is used as Date in numerous places, I cannot change that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a snippet I used to calculate the GMT offset from the `Calendar` instance and format it.  I appreciate all the help I've gotten from this site, its nice to contribute. I hope this helps someone somewhere.  Enjoy.

```
Calendar calInst = Calendar.getInstance();

//calculate the offset to keep calendar instance GMT
int gmtOffsetMilli = calInst.get(Calendar.ZONE_OFFSET);
long gmtOffsetHr = TimeUnit.HOURS.convert(gmtOffsetMilli, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

calInst = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT " + gmtOffsetHr));
```