# How do i set date formats from one country to another?

Tags: java, android, date, time

So i send a Date.toString() to an android phone, the server is in one country, how do i format the time so that it shown relative to the timezone of the phone?

For example, if the server sends 5 o clock CDT to the phone, the phone will then display 10 oclock utc ?

any ideas on how i should go about achieving this?

Comment: Do you have control over how the server formats the time?

Comment: yes i have complete control, at the moment i only send the string, what would be the best way to send it , so it can be reconstructed client side?

Answer (score 1):

If sending across a string is not an absolute requirement, an alternate solution would be to send the UTC milliseconds and re-construct the time based on the user timezone.

```
// on the sever side
final Date serverTime = new Date();
sendToClient(serverTime.getTime());
System.out.println("Time sent by server: " + serverTime);

// on the client
final long ms = receiveFromServer();
final Date clientTime = new Date();
clientTime.setTime(ms);
System.out.println("Time received by client: " + clientTime);
```

Comment: how would i reconstruct this client side in java

Comment: Updated post, try it out. Also read this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697549/how-to-make-date-locale-independent

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to send the UTC time in milliseconds, then take a look at [DateUtils.formatDateTime(...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html#formatDateTime%28android.content.Context,%20long,%20int%29) which will format and return a String using local conventions.

Use the `DateUtils.FORMAT_XXX` constants for the `flags` parameter to specify which components to include (weekday, year etc).