# Convert date to long (manually)

Tags: java, date, time

I want to convert a date to a long value (that is the milliseconds)

I have a date like

```
2/11/2014
```

I want to calculate the date in long (manual)

What I've tried

```
(2014 - 1970 ) * 31449600000 + 11 * 2592000000 + 2 * 604800000
```

This equals 1413504000000.

But http://www.fileformat.info/tip/java/date2millis.htm tells me that `1413504000000` is

```
Date (America/New_York) Thursday, October 16, 2014 8:00:00 PM EDT
Date (GMT)  Friday, October 17, 2014 12:00:00 AM GMT
Date (short/short format)   10/16/14 8:00 PM
```

Where I'm wrong?

Again, I want to do this manually, not using java code.

Comment: You are not considering leap years.

Comment: @Keppil Good point. Do you have any ideea how can I change my 'formula' ?

Comment: And while we're on the subject of leap years, you also can't assume every 4th year is a leap year. 2000 is a leap year, but 2100, 2200, and 2300 are not, even though they are %4.

Comment: Leap year, That is what you didnt consider! Also some month are 30 days some arent

Comment: You can loop through the years and check. All years divisible by 4 are leap years, except the ones divisible by 100, but including the ones divisible by 400. So, every 4 years in your range should be a leap year unless you are using dates from later than 2099.

Comment: Even if you don't want to use java code, you can look into it: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Date.java#Date.%3Cinit%3E%28int%2Cint%2Cint%2Cint%2Cint%2Cint%29

Comment: Some cases are even weirder than leap years: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11221765/2136410  and    http://stackoverflow.com/a/6841479/2136410

Comment: The date can be wrong for maximum 1-5 days, but not more..

Comment: Why do you want to do it manually?

Comment: @Sizik Well. I'm using Odata, and I have the birthdate of a field in DateTime, and I need to calculate the age of the field in the URL .. there I can only use + * - / % ... , no 'if', no 'for' etc..Maybe I'll change the way I'm trying to do this right now..

Answer (score 2):

Do not re-invent the wheel. Time/date calculations are notoriously difficult, even standard java library does not get it right. Use [JodaTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/):

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class JodaTimeSample {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
    DateTime date = DateTime.parse("2/11/2014", formatter);
    System.out.println("Date: " + date.toString());
    System.out.println("Millis: " + date.getMillis());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure you could do it manually (huh, why? - looks like homework), open [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/source-repository.html) source code and copy it. You won't invent it better. Or even better open, read and then try to write it in your editor.

Answer (score 0):

why you do manually to convert date  into long or long into date, write a simple java code which give you correct results after convention, I am using the simple programme and convert it as per my user

```
public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

            Date dt=new Date(Long.valueOf(1390973400983L));
            System.out.println(dt.toString());

            Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.set(2014, Calendar.JANUARY, 29, 11, 00, 0);

            System.out.println(cal.getTimeInMillis());
            System.out.println();

    }
```

}

for more information visit [here](https://qamanual.blogspot.in/2014/10/program-to-convert-date-into-long-and.html)